# Serverless Framework - AWS Cloudfront - S3 Static Website - OriginCustomHeader

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, infrastructure-as-code

I've an S3 static website which I want to be only accessible via Cloudfront.

I can safeguard the bucket with the below policy

```
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:UserAgent": "SecretHash"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And having the custom header User-Agent set to secret hash on the origin of the CF distribution.

My trouble comes with maintaining it as IaC.

The bucket is straight forward enough

```
          Statement:
            - Sid: PublicReadForGetBucketObjects
              Effect: Allow
              Principal: '*'
              Action:
                - s3:GetObject
              Resource: arn:aws:s3:::mybucketname/*
              Condition: 
                StringEquals: 
                  aws:UserAgent: "SecretHash".
```

I'm struggling to add this to the origin in serverless for the cloudfront distro's origin below

```
Origins:
            -
              DomainName: mybucketsite.com
              # OriginPath: mybucketorigin
              Id: bucketsitepath
              CustomOriginConfig:
                HTTPPort: 80
                HTTPSPort: 443
                OriginProtocolPolicy: 'http-only'
```

I've no doubt i'm having a dumb moment, but any help would be gratefully received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why to maintain a secret-hash and write a custom policy when AWS has already done it for you.

You can use *origin access control (OAC)* and *origin access identity (OAI)* to ensure that your private bucket is only accessible by CloudFront.

Read this post for learn more about OAI and OAC - [Restricting access to an Amazon S3 origin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Also, refer to this pattern at **ServerlessLand** to learn how to do it using IaC - [CloudFront to S3 with OAI](https://serverlessland.com/patterns/s3-cloudfront-oai)

Another useful post from AWS Knowledge Center - [How do I use my CloudFront distribution to restrict access to an Amazon S3 bucket?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudfront-access-to-amazon-s3)

Comment: OAC isn't an option for a static S3 website unfortunately

Comment: You can use OAI, since I have used that. That also solves your purpose.

Comment: They're using S3 not as an S3 origin but as a custom origin, with S3 static website hosting enabled. I agree CF S3 origin with OAC (and disabling static website hosting on S3) is generally the superior option though.